# Turning head of Makehuman model causes problems

Tags: armature, makehuman

I have an MHX rig attached to a Makehuman model in Blender and I've posed the model to look at the camera and turn her head, but there's a deformation that I don't want going on. I have "Armature" "Corrective Smooth" "Collision" and "Subsurf" modifiers on her. Nothing helps to remove except for the armature modifier for obvious reasons.[image: Notice the mouth interior sticking out, because under the jaw has lost volume, the neck appears to be twisted (Which it is, but shouldn't actually appear to be) and the collar bone area has some deformations from this as well. Both arms are positioned like the right one. Don't mind the lips, I can't figure out how to change their viewport color.]

Comment: Which is exactly the issue. Is it the neck? looks like your model is very low poly. Maybe you should add some edge loops (and correctly wheight them). Give some more info or upload your .blend file.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BE95339348EC8314!31234&authkey=!ABgnfk4sIxjLOfI&ithint=file%2cblend There's the .blend file